# Mysql TIMESTAMP TO plain date number

Tags: mysql

I need to convert mysql timestamp like `2014-01-01 10:10:10` to `20140101` in a mysql where query.

```
eg. .... WHERE ... SOME_MYSQL_FUNCTION(created) = '20140101'
```

Please note the resulting number is not seconds from epoch. It just strinpping out the time and `-` mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the query

```
 DATE_FORMAT(timestamp_column,'%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function of Mysql, like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-01-01 10:10:10', '%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE_FORMAT()` function to use it like below,

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created, '%Y%m%d') = '20140101'
```